# How Do You Find The Point Of Intersection Of $2$ Vectors?

Tags: vectors

Two lines $\textbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} t$ and $\textbf{w} = \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} u$ intersect. What point do they intersect at?

Comment: well what happens if you set them equal ? You will find t,u where both lines pass...

Comment: Like $\begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} t=\begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} u$?

Comment: Yes ! try thinking about why this works

Comment: You will have to solve a system of linear equations at the end.

Comment: Is this the equation I should be getting? $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}=-\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} t + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} u$

Comment: Yes well done now you see that you have a system of linear equations, try solving it :)

Comment: @asddf $\begin{pmatrix} 11 \\ -13 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Is that correct?

Comment: op you did a mistake, you put one vector to the other side and the other you didnt put with -to the to other side

Comment: I think the equation is right...?

Comment: You put the t vector to other side but without minus

Comment: Oh yea, oops X.X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We require the $x,y,z$ coordinates to be equal at the point of intersection, so we solve the following set of equations:

$(1)$ $$7-2t = 8+u$$

$(2)$ $$-3+5t = -1-4u$$

$(3)$ $$1+ t = -1$$

Thus from $(3)$ we get $t=-2$

Then from $(1)$ we get $7+4 = 8+u \Rightarrow u = 3$

Then we must check that this satisfies equation $(2)$

$-3+5t = -3 + 5\cdot -2 = -13 $

$-1-4u = -13$ hence there is a point of intsersection

Just plugin $u = 3$ into the equation for $w$ or $t=-2$ into your equation for $v$ to find the point of intersection.

Note the point of intersection you should get is

$\begin{pmatrix}
11\\ -13
\\ -1
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I dont see why you would answer this so thoroughly, OP was on the right track.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a point of intersection :P haha lol, so is it $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: (11,-13, -1) is the point